# Why C# WPF button binding command won't change view after using simple injector?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, simple-injector

I'm using the following articles for starter code:

[Navigating Between Views in WPF MVVM](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2018/navigating-between-views-in-wpf-mvvm/)

[Simple Injector WPF Integration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wpfintegration.html)

**Objective:**

Trying to go from View 1 to View 2 in WPF form using a button binding command and Simple Injector to inject dependencies into views. Note: These dependencies are repositories that hold data from outside sources.

**Issue:**

After injecting dependencies into my MainWindow and MainWindowViewModel using Simple Injector, my buttons no longer change my current view (to another one of my views). When using Visual Studio and debugging using breakpoints, the code seems to be stuck in a loop forever in the `CanExecute` function of RelayCommand.cs (see [Navigating Between Views in WPF MVVM](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2018/navigating-between-views-in-wpf-mvvm/)), where something is calling it over and over again. I can't debug more into the `CanExecute` function because there's a lot of code that gets passed over (from DLLs and such). When not using breakpoints, it just appears as if my button does nothing.

I get no button errors in the output window and no exceptions are thrown. The command binding is working because I can see the function `OnGo2Screen` found in MainWindowViewModel.cs being called while debugging. After the `OnGo2Screen` is called, it moves through the code as expected until it gets stuck in the `CanExecute`.

**What I've Tried**

I have checked my MainWindow's data context and I can see that it has all the correct functions.

I made a separate project for the [Navigating Between Views in WPF MVVM](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2018/navigating-between-views-in-wpf-mvvm/) article and I was able to get the views to change just fine. But whenever I try to use Simple Injector, my buttons break.

I noticed that when not using Simple Injector, the code moves from the `CanExecute` function to the `CanExecuteChanged` EventHandler and does the remove and add mutators, and afterwards change the view as expected. However when using Simple Injector, it does not do this.

**The Code**

I'm using my App.xaml.cs as the startup program where my App.xaml has a Build Action of "Page".

SimulationCaseView is View 1 (The default starting view).

StreamsView is View 2 (Just another view).

UserControl3 is View 3 (Just another view).

Below is my code. Refer to the two links provided for any remaining code, as I based a lot of the functions on that.

*App.xaml*

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.Desktop.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Desktop.Views">
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type views:SimulationCaseViewModel}">
            <views:SimulationCaseView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type views:StreamsViewModel}">
            <views:StreamsView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type views:UserControl3ViewModel}">
            <views:UserControl3 />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

*App.xaml.cs*

```
namespace MyApp.Desktop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var container = Bootstrap();

            // Any additional other configuration, e.g. of your desired MVVM toolkit.

            RunApplication(container);
        }


        private static Container Bootstrap()
        {
            // Create the container as usual.
            var container = new Container();

            // Register your types, for instance:
            container.Register<IPreferencesRepository, PreferencesRepository>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
            container.Register<IStreamRepository, StreamRepository>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

            // Register your windows and view models:
            container.Register<MainWindow>();
            container.Register<MainWindowViewModel>();

            container.Verify();

            return container;
        }

        private static void RunApplication(Container container)
        {
            try
            {
                var app = new App();
                var mainWindow = container.GetInstance<MainWindow>();
                MainWindowViewModel viewModel = container.GetInstance<MainWindowViewModel>();
                mainWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
                app.Run(mainWindow);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Desktop.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Desktop"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Desktop.Views">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindowViewModel.cs*

```
namespace MyApp.Desktop.Views
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private IPageViewModel _currentPageViewModel;
        private List<IPageViewModel> _pageViewModels;

        public List<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pageViewModels == null)
                    _pageViewModels = new List<IPageViewModel>();

                return _pageViewModels;
            }
        }

        public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPageViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                _currentPageViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel");
            }
        }

        private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
                PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);

            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels
                .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);
        }

        private void OnGo1Screen(object obj)
        {
            ChangeViewModel(PageViewModels[0]);
        }

        private void OnGo2Screen(object obj)
        {
            ChangeViewModel(PageViewModels[1]);
        }
        private void OnGo3Screen(object obj)
        {
            ChangeViewModel(PageViewModels[2]);
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel(IStreamRepository streamRepository)
        {
            // Add available pages and set page
            PageViewModels.Add(new SimulationCaseViewModel(streamRepository));
            PageViewModels.Add(new StreamsViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new UserControl3ViewModel());

            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];

            Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo1Screen", OnGo1Screen);
            Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo2Screen", OnGo2Screen);
            Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo3Screen", OnGo3Screen);
        }
    }
}
```

*SimulationCaseView.xaml*

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Desktop.Views.SimulationCaseView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Desktop"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="280" d:DesignWidth="280">
    <Grid>
        <Button
            Content="Go to Streams"
            Command="{Binding GoTo2}"
            Width="90" Height="30" Margin="166,220,24,30">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

*SimulationCaseViewModel.cs*

```
namespace MyApp.Desktop.Views
{
    public class SimulationCaseViewModel : BaseViewModel, IPageViewModel
    {
        private ICommand _goTo2;
        private readonly IStreamRepository _repo;
        public SimulationCaseViewModel(IStreamRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
            Application application = _repo.GetApplicationReference();
            CurrentSimulationCases = new ObservableCollection<SimulationCase>();
            Streams = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            foreach (SimulationCase simulationCase in application.SimulationCases)
            {
                CurrentSimulationCases.Add(simulationCase);
            }
            //FetchStreams = new RelayCommand(OnFetch);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<SimulationCase> CurrentSimulationCases { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<object> Streams { get; private set; }

        public ICommand GoTo2
        {
            get
            {
                return _goTo2 ?? (_goTo2 = new RelayCommand(x =>
                {
                    Mediator.Notify("GoTo2Screen", "");
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help as to why the buttons aren't working is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The rest of the code is found [here](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2018/navigating-between-views-in-wpf-mvvm/).
I have debugged my code and the button command fires and ```Mediator.Notify``` hits. There are no errors in the output view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

The problem is in the `Lifestyle` of your ViewModel that must be set to a `Singleton` and not to the default `Transient`.

```
    private static Container Bootstrap()
    {
        // Create the container as usual.
        var container = new Container();

        // Register your types, for instance:


        // Register your windows and view models:
        //container.Register<MainWindow>(Lifestyle.Singleton); //not needed
        container.Register<MainWindowViewModel>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

        container.Verify();

        return container;
    }
```

Then you can start the app in a simple way

```
    private static void RunApplication(Container container)
    {
        try
        {
            var mainWindow = container.GetInstance<MainWindow>();
            var app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run(mainWindow);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log the exception and exit
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The full code is on [github](https://github.com/giuliohome/MvvmNavigation).

### Long Answer - TL;DR

When you call the `container.Verify` in the `Bootstrap` you will create an instance of `MainWindowViewModel` to verify its instantiation and another to verify the `MainWindow` class.

*Incidentally, you could solve your issue by simply not verifying the container!*

So the **2**nd solution is

```
        //container.Register<MainWindow>(); // => Lifestyle.Transient;
        container.Register<MainWindowViewModel>(); // => Lifestyle.Transient;

        //container.Verify();
```

Now, notice that you have the `Mediator` subscription in the `MainWindowViewModel` c.tor.

```
    public static void Subscribe(string token, Action<object> callback)
    {
        if (!pl_dict.ContainsKey(token))
        {
            var list = new List<Action<object>>();
            list.Add(callback);
            pl_dict.Add(token, list);
        }
        else
        {
            bool found = false;
            //foreach (var item in pl_dict[token])
            //    if (item.Method.ToString() == callback.Method.ToString())
            //        found = true;
            if (!found)
                pl_dict[token].Add(callback);
        }
    }
```

The `foreach` loop - that I've commented only above (*and it is the **3**rd alternative option to solve your issue*) - will make you skip the call to the second correct ViewModel's methods and will leave you with the first wrong ones (remember that the `Bootstrap` verification created it twice).
If you want a **4**th alternative solution, with the classical `IComponent` interface of the [Mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern#C#)

```
public interface IComponent
{
     void OnGo1Screen(object obj);
     void OnGo2Screen(object obj);
}
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel, IComponent
```

you can also move the subscription out of the c.tor

```
  public MainWindowViewModel()
  {
     // Add available pages and set page
     PageViewModels.Add(new UserControl1ViewModel());
     PageViewModels.Add(new UserControl2ViewModel());

     CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];

     //Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo1Screen", OnGo1Screen);
     //Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo2Screen", OnGo2Screen);
  }
```

into your `Program`:

```
            var context = mainWindow.DataContext as IComponent;
            Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo1Screen", context.OnGo1Screen);
            Mediator.Subscribe("GoTo2Screen", context.OnGo2Screen);
```

Comment: Great answer. After following what you said in your short answer as well as adding ```base.DataContext = viewModel;``` to my MainWindow.xaml.cs, everything worked.

Answer (score 4):

### How to resolve?

Call this method after you update your command states:

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

### Why doesn't it update?

Commands only update when these general events happen:

- `KeyUp`
- `MouseUp`
- `GotKeyboardFocus`
- `LostKeyboardFocus`

See this source code for details: [CommandDevice.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandDevice.cs,140)

For other controls, it has more events to refresh:

- IncreaseRepeatButton repeated when long pressing
- `DataGrid` ...
- `SinglePageViewer` ...

You can double click the `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` method of [this link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandDevice.cs,140) to view other events that refresh the command states.

So if your updates happen not in those events, your command states will not be updated.

### Other Info

You said that when using Visual Studio and debugging using breakpoints, the code seems to be stuck in a loop forever in the `CanExecute` function of RelayCommand.cs.

That's not a loop for `CanExecute`, that is the `GotKeyboardFocus` and `LostKeyboardFocus` event when your active window is changing between your application and Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new to WPF, so I'm not sure how to use ```CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();```. I assume this code needs to go in the RelayCommand.cs file? Where would be the best place for this?

Comment: But the `GoTo2` command has always `CanExecute == true`. There is nothing to update.

Comment: Despite the upvotes, this has nothing to do with the issue in the question here.